# How to Insert more than 1000 record using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

**I need to insert more than 1000 records into SQL Server. But using my code I am able to insert only 1000 records. Please help me.**

```
using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection,SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null))
{
     s.DestinationTableName = TableName;
     s.BatchSize = 10000;
     s.BulkCopyTimeout = 1800;
     foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
     {
         s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
     }
     s.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you insert 1001 records?

Comment: It is only inserting first 1000 records and discards all records after 1000.

Comment: Does it reach your timeout or is a exception thrown, some error messages?

Comment: it is not throwing any exception. if I comment the batchsize and BulkCopyTimeout then also it is doing the same.

Comment: What about `dt` object, maybe you pass only 1000 rows to it?

Comment: I have total 1730 records in dt object. Is there any type of restriction in SqlBulkCopy? Or I need to made any change in SQL Server settings?

Comment: You are, of course, sure that bulk copy does not insert more than 1000 rows. I.e. you are not using the right-click select on table in management studio that does a select top 1000 only showing you the first 1000 rows?

Comment: @larsts right-click select on table in management studio gives me 2 options select top 1000 and edit to 200 row.

Comment: I was trying to ask if you were sure that the table does not contain more than 1000 rows after your C# code has run, seems weird that there should be a 1000 row limit on Bulk Copy. But if you only execute the select generated by management studio the database will only return the first 1000 rows. How are you checking that there is only 1000 rows inserted?

Comment: I am using a query "select * from TableName" and returns only 1000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the real time working code which i used in my project to insert the bulk data from excel to the SQL server

C# code:

```
public static DataSet Bindgrid_StoreInSQL(string path)
    {


            string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower();
            string connString = "";
            if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable Exceldt = ds.Tables[0];

            //creating object of SqlBulkCopy    
            SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(OneStopMethods_Common.constring_Property);
            //assigning Destination table name    
            objbulk.DestinationTableName = "Tern_boq";


            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Bill_No", "Bill_No");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Page_No", "Page_No");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ItemNo", "ItemNo");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Description", "Description");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("BOQ_Qty", "BOQ_Qty");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UNIT", "UNIT");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Category1", "Category1");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Category2", "Category2");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Category3", "Category3");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Estimated_UnitRate", "Estimated_UnitRate");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Estimated_Amount", "Estimated_Amount");



            //inserting Datatable Records to DataBase    
            conn.Open();
            objbulk.WriteToServer(Exceldt);


            SqlDatabase obj = new SqlDatabase(OneStopMethods_Common.constring_Property);
            string selquery = " select * from Tern_boq";
            return obj.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, selquery);




    }
```

Its works fine,Hope this can give you some idea,Please let me know your your thoughts or suggestions

Comment: Working fine.I am able to insert more than 1000 rows. Thanks man :)

Comment: Its my pleasure and am really happy that i could help you..:)..Kindly let me know if anything else is required..Happy sharing..:)

Comment: oneStopMethods_Common.constring_Property is not being recognized. Do I need to add a reference to something??

Comment: Hi,

Its just a connection string , you can simply replace like this

Before change:

SqlDatabase obj = new SqlDatabase(OneStopMethods_Common.constring_Property);

After Change:

SqlDatabase obj = new SqlDatabase("Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password");


Note : In the above connection string replace your servername and DatabaseName appropriately. this may also help you :https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/


Hope it will help, share your feedback

thanks

Comment: Hi,how can i pass the value of current date i dont have that column in excel... through ColumnMapping it is not possible objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("", "CreatedOn");